# LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 authorization fails

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

LinkedIn authorization fails even for r_basicprofile scope.

Here is the authorization request that I'm trying to execute

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/linkedIn&state=987654321

client_id is changed of course.

I'm getting response 401 - Unauthorized.

```
{"timestamp":1465218804004,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed: Could not obtain user details from token","path":"/login/linkedIn"}
```

I've checked App permissions, r_basicprofile is selected and the client_id is correct.